# AnjularJS Issues with multiple modules with in same view

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my main page implementing routes with the help of **demo** module,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="demo">
    <!--HEADER - NAVIGATION-->
    <p align="center">
        <b><u>My First AngularJS Demo App!</u></b></p>
    <p align="center">
        <a href="#DataBinding">Data Binding</a> | <a href="#Expressions">Expressions</a>
    </p>
    <!--INCLUDE REFERENC AJS SCRITS-->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!--INCLUDE REFERENC AJS SCRITS-->

    <script>
        // Code goes here
        var demo = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
        demo.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'Default.htm'
            }).
    when('/DataBinding', {
        templateUrl: 'DataBinding.htm',
        controller : 'myCtrl'
    }).
otherwise({ templateUrl: 'main.html' });
        })
    </script>


<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp1", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "Sachin";
        $scope.lastName = "Tendulkar";
    });
</script>
```

Now DataBinding.htm is making use of another module with in main page called **myApp1**. Here is DataBinding.htm code,

```
<div na-app="myApp1">
{{ firstName + " " +  lastName }}
</div>
```

**Expected output :** When I click on Data Binding, page should display Sachin Tendulkar

DataBinding.htm this not working whn I click on DataBinding link! its just showing 
**`{{ firstName + " " +  lastName }}`** instead of actual values.

Any Help appreciated!

Comment: pls create a fiddle with this

Comment: Why do you want to add 2 modules to your page? You know you can inject one module into another and just reuse the functionality of that model. The other thing is there seems to be a spelling mistake: `na-app` instead of `ng-app`